# How to read config file in vs2017

Tags: c#, selenium, configurationmanager

I am keep getting error message

> System.ArgumentNullException:'Argument'url' cannot be null. Parameter name:'value'.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Selenium.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;

namespace onlineShoesStore_2017
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            // IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"]);
        }
    }
}
```

My configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="URL" value="https://anupdamoda.github.io/AceOnlineShoePortal/SignIn.html/"/>    
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Edit:

John, I checked the bin/Debug folder and found onlineShoesStore_2017.exe.config file. This is a note(.txt) file, not sure what to do with this. I am trying to run this application and got the following error.

> Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20
> (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355})
> on port 11131 Only local connections are allowed. Please see
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for
> suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started
> successfully.
>
> DevTools listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:11148/devtools/browser/c8911731-3046-4c86-b8b5-ddfa5db757ff
> [3880:11524:1129/132820.948:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)]
> [13:28:20.948] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read
> descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is
> not functioning. (0x1F)
> [3880:11524:1129/132820.952:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)]
> [13:28:20.951] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read
> descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is
> not functioning. (0x1F)
> [3880:11524:1129/132820.952:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)]
> [13:28:20.952] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read
> descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is
> not functioning. (0x1F)

I even tried to run with Visual studio 2019 but got the same error.

Comment: The setting looks correct and worked in my VS 2019. However, I recall an issue I had some time back and I found there is another config file that may get used in debug mode. If this is debug mode, then look in the `bin/Debug` folder for a file named… `onlineShoesStore_2017.exe.config`… it may be using this file. Just a guess but… checking cannot hurt.

Comment: _”John, I checked the bin/Debug folder and found onlineShoesStore_2017.exe.config file. This is a note(.txt) file, not sure what to do with this.”_ … you are correct, it IS a simple text file. Is what you are supposed to do with it… is… _“Check To See If It Contains The”_ ` </appSettings>` as you have posted. If the code is there, then that was all I was checking. If its NOT there, then add it there.

Comment: It is NOT difficult to “check” if the value from the config is null, BEFORE you pass it to the browser. The errors you show, have nothing to do with the config file. These look like Chrome and USB errors. Once the string is read correctly from the config file, then you are done! Whatever happens when you pass the string to the browser is out of the hands of the configuration file or configuration manager. I am just saying that your original question is about the config file and has evolved into chrome/USB errors.

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the exception.